# how to not include certain functions in a header file for use in C programing

Tags: c, linux, gcc, c-header

To paint the picture let's imagine we have a header called `headertest.h` and where going to use it in a file called `test.c`

It's context look like this

```c
#include <stddef.h>

extern size_t string_lenght(const char *);

size_t string_lenght(const char *str)
{
    size_t n = 0;
    while (str[n] != '\0')
        n++;
    return (n);
}
```

It's purpose is to count the lenght of a given string and give output as **size_t**

if we include it in our `test.c` file like this and compile with `gcc -o test test.c`

```c
#include "<location to header>/headertest.h"
    
int main ()
{
   
}
```

it compiles successfully and by running the command `du -b test | awk '{print $1}'` it outputs **16504**, telling us it's size is 16504 bytes. However if we comment `#include` and just leave `int main ()` and recompile test and run the same command again, we get **16464**.

so in conclusion, how do you tell C to specifically only include a function when compiling only if it's present in the main C program, from a self made header file.

Comment: https://tetzank.github.io/posts/removing-unused-code/

Comment: You may or may not be interested in spelling “length” correctly.

Comment: In other words, look in your compiler documentation for the compiler flag that causes the compiler to remove dead code.

Comment: A header should not normally define a function as yours does.  You can't use that header in more than one source file in any program.  If you defined that function with `static inline size_t`, then it would only be included if used.

Comment: works fantastic, thank you Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

It is not uncommon to use pre-compiler defines in a header file to exclude code for one OS or another...

```
#ifdef __linux__ 
    void Do_one_thing(void);
#elif _WIN32
    void Do_another_thing(void);
#else __APPLE__
    void Do_yet_another_thing(void);
#endif
```

Comment: where would for example define --linux--, the headerfile, main C file or somewhere else?

Comment: @tomas - the compiler you are using will include them.  For example listing defines on Linux use `gcc -dM -E - </dev/null`, on generic UNIX compilers (OS) use `unix __unix__ __unix`,  when using GCC on Windows use:  `gcc -dM -E - <NUL:`.  If you need something else, [most development environments allow you to create your own.](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/gccintro_34.html)

Comment: alright, i see.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions from [article mentioned in comments](https://tetzank.github.io/posts/removing-unused-code) are pretty good, but they have their own quirks:

- `static` works great for private stuff, but makes little sense for things that may be directly called from more than one `.c` file
- smarter things like `lto`, or linker garbage collection require compiler/linker support and each impose their own quirks/cons

Libraries often use macros to explicitly disable/enable certain features.
The advantages are:

- simplicity and portability
- unused code isn't even compiled, so you can also reduce build time
- less dependencies if feature requires extra lib
- it also allows for switching functionality that isn't separate function (e.g. param validation)

Example:

```c
// file mylib.h
#ifndef MYLIB_FOO_OFF // ifndef - "if macro not defined"
 void mylib_foo();
#endif

#ifndef MYLIB_BAR_OFF
 #include <otherlib.h>
 void mylib_foo(otherlib_struct s);
#endif

// file mylib.c
#include "mylib.h"

#ifndef MYLIB_FOO_OFF
 void mylib_foo() { /* implementation */ };
#endif

#ifndef MYLIB_BAR_OFF
 void mylib_foo(otherlib_struct s) { /* implementation */ }
#endif
```

Then if you don't need `mylib_bar()` you can just instruct your's compiler/build system to define `MYLIB_BAR_OFF`, e.g `gcc -DMYLIB_BAR_OFF main.c mylib.c`.
Preprocessor will then remove code within `#ifndef` directives scope, as if it wasn't typed in the first place

Example from real world library: https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#overview